# How to filter a collection based on CheckBox value (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have an Employee Table. and I have an WPF Screen. in screen I want to have an "Exclude Former Employees" checkbox (checked as default) when it checked I generate report there is no Former Employee in table. but  When I remove check in checkbox I want to see former employee.

See in my xaml:

```
<CheckBox Content="Exclude Former Employees" IsChecked="{Binding ExcludeFormerEmployees}" Margin="4" />
```

in ViewModel:

My Generate Report Button Command (to take employee report.)

```
private void GenerateReports()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var harmonyDatas = ConvertRawDatas(SelectedYear, SelectedMonths, SelectedEmployees);

            harmonyDatas.ForEach(hd =>
            {
                if (_excludeWeekends) hd.ExcludeWeekends();
                if (_excludePublicHolidays) hd.Exclude(_publicHolidays);
                if (_excludeFormerEmployees) hd.ExcludeFormerEmployees();
            });

            ParticularEntries = harmonyDatas.SelectMany(hd => hd.Select(range => new EntryReportParticular
            {
                Employee = range.Employee,
                Entry = range.Start,
                Exit = range.End,
                Region = range.Region
            }));

            DailyEntries = ParticularEntries.GroupBy(p => p.Employee.Id).SelectMany(pe => pe.GroupBy(peg => peg.Entry.Date).Select(peg =>
            {
                var firstPe = peg.First();

                return new EntryReportDaily
                {
                    Employee = firstPe.Employee,
                    Day = firstPe.Entry.Date,
                    TotalWorkingHours = peg.Sum(entry => entry.Duration.TotalHours)
                };
            }));

            MonthlyEntries = MonthlyEntries = harmonyDatas.Select(hd => new EntryReportMonthly
            {
                Employee = hd.Employee,
                NofWorkingDaysAtOrigLoc = hd.GetNofDaysInMonthAtOrigLoc(),
                NofWorkingDaysAtOtherLoc = hd.GetNofDaysInMonthAtOtherLoc(),
                TotalWorkingHoursAtOrigLoc = hd.GetMonthlyWorkingHoursAtOrigLoc(),
                TotalWorkingHoursAtOtherLoc = hd.GetMonthlyWorkingHoursAtOtherLoc()
            });

            IsBusy = false;
        }

        #endregion


private bool _excludeFormerEmployees;
        public bool ExcludeFormerEmployees
        {
            get { return _excludeFormerEmployees; }
            set { Set(ref _excludeFormerEmployees, value); }
        }
```

In Generate Report Button Command (It's employee reports)

```
   if (_excludeFormerEmployees) hd.ExcludeFormerEmployees();
```

in Method:

```
 public void ExcludeFormerEmployees()
        { 
            RemoveAll(ef => Employee.IsDelegation==false&& Employee.Status==0);

        }
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please describe what actually happens now and what is `RemoveAll` method doing?

Comment: Of Course,When I clicked Generate Reports button. All employees come to screen.I want to add a checkbox to remove former employees on the screen.with default clicked.When I clicked "Exclude Former Employees" checkbox former employee remove to screen. else I should see all employees.
RemoveAll (as I know) remove them (status=0 and isdelegation = false is Former Employee)
Also I give detailed and edited question

Answer (score 1):

You should use collection view filtering by setting the [`ICollectionView.Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter?view=netframework-4.8) property instead of removing the items from the collection:

```
public bool ExcludeFormerEmployees
{
  get { return _excludeFormerEmployees; }
  set 
  { 
    Set(ref _excludeFormerEmployees, value); 

    // Get the colection view of the employee collection
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Employees);
    collectionView.Filter = 
      item => value 
        ? !(item as Employee).IsDelegation && (item as Employee).Status == 0 // Apply filter
        : true; // Clear filter and show all
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is this.Employees ?

Comment: Since you you didn't posted the complete context related code, I had to make my answer generic.`Employees` is the imaginary example collection that contains the employee objects. I don't know how you call this collection and what it exactly contains. But it doesn't really matter. It's the collection you want to filter based on the `ExcludeFormerEmployees` value. You have to slightly adjust the code example and replace `Employees` with your collection.